# Repository data cache management with RxJava and switchIfEmpty()

Tags: android, caching, rx-java, repository-pattern

I have two fragments using a common Repository.

I'm trying to implement a cache management system for this Repository.

The idea is :
One of the fragment is loaded, it calls the `getData()` method, this method make a network call to the remote JSON Api using `getDataFromNetwork()`, get the result and put it in the cache as a `List<Aqicn>` (the `data` variable in my code).

The next fragment is loaded. If it happens before 60 seconds then there is no network call, the data come directly from the cache within my data List using `getDataFromMemory()`.

The RxJava `Observable.switchIfEmpty()` is used to know if the Observable (my ArrayList) is empty or not and call the right method.

I didn't know how to debut this so I just put a button on my main layout. When I launch my app the first fragment is automatically loaded , `getData()` is called for the first time. When I push this button it loads the second fragment, `getData()` is called a second time.

If I push this button before 60 seconds I should not have a network call to the JSON api but... I have one, I always get a second network call and my cache data is not used. What's wrong with my code ?

```
public class CommonRepository implements Repository {
    private static final String TAG = CommonRepository.class.getSimpleName();
    private long timestamp;
    private static final long STALE_MS = 60 * 1000; // Data is stale after 60 seconds
    private PollutionApiService pollutionApiService;
    private ArrayList<Aqicn> data;


    public CommonRepository(PollutionApiService pollutionApiService) {
        this.pollutionApiService = pollutionApiService;
        this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getDataFromNetwork(String city, String authToken) {
        Observable<Aqicn> aqicn = pollutionApiService.getPollutionObservable(city, authToken)
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Aqicn>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Aqicn aqicn) {
                        data.add(aqicn);
                    }
                });
        return aqicn;
    }

    private boolean isUpToDate() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp < STALE_MS;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getDataFromMemory() {
        if (isUpToDate()) {
            return Observable.from(data);
        } else {
            timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            data.clear();
            return Observable.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getData(String city, String authToken) {
        return getDataFromMemory().switchIfEmpty(getDataFromNetwork(city, authToken));
    }
}
```

**======= EDIT : I simplified my code to the minimum ===========**

```
public class CommonRepository implements Repository {
    private PollutionApiService pollutionApiService;
    private static Observable<Aqicn> cachedData = null;


    public CommonRepository(PollutionApiService pollutionApiService) {
        this.pollutionApiService = pollutionApiService;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getDataFromNetwork(String city, String authToken) {
        Observable<Aqicn> aqicn = pollutionApiService.getPollutionObservable(city, authToken);
        cachedData = aqicn;
        return aqicn;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Aqicn> getData(String city, String authToken) {
        if(cachedData == null) {
            return getDataFromNetwork(city, authToken);
        }
        return cachedData;
    }
}
```

And just realized that no matter what I'm doing, when I do `return cachedData` a network call is done...

**===== EDIT Problem spotted but no solution found ==========**

The thing is in my constructor I initiale my pollutionApiService. 
This use Dagger for the JSON request and returns an Observable :

```
public interface PollutionApiService {
    @GET("feed/{city}/")
    Observable<Aqicn> getPollutionObservable(@Path("city") String city, @Query("token") String token);
}
```

I don't know how all this works in details but I interprate like this. Dagger create a PollutionApiService provider that is an Observable. When I do `return cachedData` this Observable is subscribed so the network call is done... but no idea how neither how to fix it. The fact is every time I do a `return cachedData` there is a network call.

Comment: Do you want to cache all requests with given params? If you call first getData with city: 'Hamburg' and auth: X and after that 'Berlin', 'X', should both requests be cached for 60 seconds? In your current implementation you will just add elements to your cache for each request.

Comment: The parameters are both the same in my both calls.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the cache-behaviour with following classes.

In order to use the Cache class, you will need following dependency: https://cache2k.org/docs/1.0/user-guide.html#android

```
interface Repository {
    Single<Result> getData(String param1, String param2);
}

class RepositoryImpl implements Repository {

    private final Cache<String, Result> cache;

    private final Function2<String, String, String> calculateKey;

    RepositoryImpl(Cache<String, Result> cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.calculateKey = (s, s2) -> s + s2;
    }

    @Override
    public Single<Result> getData(String param1, String param2) {
        Maybe<Result> networkFallback = getFromNetwork(param1, param2, calculateKey).toMaybe();

        return getFromCache(param1, param2, calculateKey).switchIfEmpty(networkFallback)
                .toSingle();
    }

    private Single<Result> getFromNetwork(String param1, String param2, Function2<String, String, String> calculateKey) {
        return Single.fromCallable(Result::new)
                .doOnSuccess(result -> {
                    if (!cache.containsKey(calculateKey.apply(param1, param2))) {
                        System.out.println("save in cache");

                        String apply = calculateKey.apply(param1, param2);
                        cache.put(apply, result);
                    }
                }) // simulate network request
                .delay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private Maybe<Result> getFromCache(String param1, String param2, Function2<String, String, String> calculateKey) {
        return Maybe.defer(() -> {
            String key = calculateKey.apply(param1, param2);

            if (cache.containsKey(key)) {
                System.out.println("get from cache");
                return Maybe.just(cache.get(key));
            } else {
                return Maybe.empty();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Result {
}
```

Test behaviour:

```
@Test
    // Call getData two times with equal params. First request gets cached. Second request requests from network too, because cash has already expired.
void getData_requestCashed_cashExpiredOnRequest() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    Cache<String, Result> cacheMock = mock(Cache.class);
    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(cacheMock);
    Repository rep = new RepositoryImpl(cacheMock);

    Result result = new Result();
    when(cacheMock.containsKey(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> false);
    when(cacheMock.get(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> result);

    Single<Result> data1 = rep.getData("hans", "wurst");
    Single<Result> data2 = rep.getData("hans", "wurst");

    // Action
    data1.test()
            .await()
            .assertValueAt(0, r -> r != result);

    // Validate first Subscription: save to cache
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(2))
            .containsKey(anyString());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(1))
            .put(anyString(), any());

    data2.test()
            .await()
            .assertValueAt(0, r -> r != result);

    // Validate second Subscription: save to cache
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(2))
            .containsKey(anyString());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(1))
            .put(anyString(), any());
}

@Test
    // Call getData two times with different params for each request. Values cashed but only for each request. Second request will hit network again due to different params.
void getData_twoDifferentRequests_cacheNotHit() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    Cache<String, Result> cacheMock = mock(Cache.class);
    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(cacheMock);
    Repository rep = new RepositoryImpl(cacheMock);

    Result result = new Result();
    when(cacheMock.containsKey(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> false);
    when(cacheMock.get(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> result);

    Single<Result> data1 = rep.getData("hans", "wurst");
    Single<Result> data2 = rep.getData("hansX", "wurstX");

    // Action
    data1.test()
            .await()
            .assertValueAt(0, r -> r != result);

    // Validate first Subscription: save to cache
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(2))
            .containsKey(anyString());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(1))
            .put(anyString(), any());

    // Action
    data2.test()
            .await()
            .assertValueAt(0, r -> r != result);

    // Validate second Subscription: save to cache
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(2))
            .containsKey(anyString());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(1))
            .put(anyString(), any());
}


@Test
    // Call getData two times with equal params. First request hit network. Second request hits cache. Cache does not expire between two requests.
void getData_twoEqualRequests_cacheHitOnSecond() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    Cache<String, Result> cacheMock = mock(Cache.class);
    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(cacheMock);
    Repository rep = new RepositoryImpl(cacheMock);

    Result result = new Result();
    when(cacheMock.containsKey(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> false);

    Single<Result> data1 = rep.getData("hans", "wurst");
    Single<Result> data2 = rep.getData("hans", "wurst");

    // Action
    data1.test()
            .await();

    // Validate first Subscription: save to cache
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(2))
            .containsKey(anyString());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(0))
            .get(anyString());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(1))
            .put(anyString(), any());

    when(cacheMock.containsKey(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> true);
    when(cacheMock.get(anyString())).thenAnswer(invocation -> result);

    TestObserver<Result> sub2 = data2.test()
            .await()
            .assertNoErrors()
            .assertValueCount(1)
            .assertComplete();

    // Validate second subscription: load from cache
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(1))
            .containsKey(anyString());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(0))
            .put(anyString(), any());
    inOrder.verify(cacheMock, times(1))
            .get(anyString());

    sub2.assertResult(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I only have to cache an Arraylist of 10 integers... it should be easy to do this without using an external lib full of things I don't need since it was implemented to deal with more complex caching tasks.